# Как правильно инициализировать указатель?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, указатели, выделение-памяти

Имеется класс, в котором значения по умолчанию  присваиваются сразу при создании объекта класса:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum state { empty, deleted, used };//Константы для заполнения состояния ячейки
class guest
{
public:
    char pasport[12];
    string name;
    int birthyear;
    string adris;
    string purpose_of_travel;
    guest* head;//Указатель на голову списка
    guest* next;//Указатель на следующий элемент списка при возникновении коллизии
    int st;//Состояние ячейки
    guest(const char *pasport_m = "8015-175572", const string name_m = "No Name",
        const int birthyear_m = 0, const string address_m = "No Adress",
        const string purpose_of_travel_m = "No Info" , const int st_m=0,   guest *next_m=NULL, guest* head=NULL);
};
```

В части кода, где я создаю новый указатель типа *guest и выделаю под него память происходит ошибка присваивания значений.
Вот эта часть кода:

```
guest *temp = (guest*)malloc(sizeof(guest));
                tesst->next = temp;
                temp->name = cur_guest->name;
                temp->adris = cur_guest->adris;
                temp->birthyear = cur_guest->birthyear;
                temp->next = NULL;
```

что не так делаю? При сборке ошибку не выдает. Ошибка вылезает непосредственно при отладке. Пишет вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"Только не это, шеф! Только не это!"* Не выделяйте память сложному классу с конструктором через `malloc`! Только через `new`! И вообще, в С++ - забудьте о `malloc` вообще!!

Answer (score 5):

При выделении через `malloc` вы просто получаете неинициализированную память. Конструктор не вызывается, все ваши `string` на самом деле никакие не строки, а просто кусок памяти того же размера с мусором.

В С++ используйте `new`, только `new`! Никаких `malloc` - по крайней мере пока не научитесь точно понимать, что и как работает (это для тех, кто сейчас начнет рассказывать о placement new).

Вся инициализация полей должна идти через конструктор, который автоматически вызывается при использовании `new`. И вообще, делая поля открытыми, вы фактически отвергаете одного из китов ООП - инкапсуляцию.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про инкапсуляцию знаю, мог бы разработать структуру, но взял за основу класс, потом переделаю в private метод.. А чем malloc отличается от new? Я смотрел создание линейного списка, там память через маллок выделают

Comment: @Harry - а что new[] нельзя?:)  (автору вопроса) да, в с++ нужно вызывать new/new[] - они знают о классах и умеют с ними "корректно работать". А malloc/calloc/realloc - нет

Comment: @KoVadim откройте первую и вторую ссылку, в которой объясняются темы про односвязные линейные списки. Там вы увидите, что память выделают при помощи malloc(). И для вас, я могу изменить слово class на struct. Суть вопроса не в этом была, я учусь программировать, поэтому члены пока сделал открытыми для доступа к ним.

Comment: какие ссылки, где они? В любом случае, если внутри структуры/класса только "простые типы" (int, char, указатели на простые типы), то оно будет работать. Правда если очень-очень сильно придираться, до 20 плюсов, создание классов-структур через malloc - UB:) - ведь только new "создает объект", а malloc - не создавал. Почему в разных туториалах используется malloc - да никто не парится, копипастят старые сишные куски кода, особо не разбираясь

Comment: @KoVadim почему то думал, что new это что то простое. А вот malloc - это очень крутая штука, которая только для сложных структур. Спасибо, что помогли разобраться, исправил кусок кода на new все заработало.

Comment: new - это очень хитрая штука. Она вызывает вначале выделение памяти (это может быть даже обычный malloc, а может быть хитрое выделение с специального места в памяти, которое заточено под эти объекты), а потом вызов соответствующий конструкторов. Также new "дает жизнь объекту"

Comment: @Iskander На первых порах, когда я только начинал разбираться в ООП, я тоже не понимал, для чего поля класса нужно делать закрытыми, и объявлял доступ к ним как public. Но со временем обнаружил, что когда программа разрастается до некоторых размеров и число классов в ней превышает определённый порог, начинается сплошная путаница и каша: например, в каких случаях надо вызывать n=myclass.GetLength(), а в каких n=myclass.length; где в коде мне нужно явно присваивать значение полю, а где это возможно только через метод, чтобы ничего не поломать в классе. В общем, со временем завязал так делать))

Comment: @LShadow77 , читая книгу Стивена Праты по C++ я с этим разобрался, что члены должны быть закрытыми, что бы пользователь(условный программист) который пользуется твоим классом через открытый интерфейс мог делать только то, что ты (разработчик класса) задумал и не мог изменять значения так, как хочет он. Тут я скорее сделал их открытыми, что бы была возможность обратиться из любой точки программы и показать значение сейчас